# How do i mock IEnumerable.First<T>() method using Rhino mocks?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have an `IEnumerable<T>` collection and I want to mock the `First<T>()` method call.
When I tried doing that I get this:

> Previous method 'IEnumerator.MoveNext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.

I am pasting the code below:

```
IEnumerable<T> collection = MockRepository
    .GenerateStub<IEnumerable<T>>();
collection
    .Stub(x => x.First<T>())
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Return(MockRepository.GenerateStub<T>());
```

But the `x.First<T>` throws the above exception. How do I solve it? I tried returning an `IEnumerator` by mocking the `GetEnumerator()` method call as well. It didn't help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `T` is present because the code is in a generic function.

You can't stub a call to `First<T>()` because it's a static extension method. It isn't defined in `IEnumerable<T>`, it's a member of `Enumerable`.

So, you'll need to stub `GetEnumerator()` on your `IEnumerable<T>` stub to return an `IEnumerator<T>` stub, which returns a stub of the type you want:

```
IEnumerator<T> enumerator = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IEnumerator<T>>();
enumerator.Stub(x => x.MoveNext()).Return(true);
enumerator.Stub(x => x.Current).Return(MockRepository.GenerateStub<T>());
enumerator.Stub(x => x.MoveNext()).Return(false);

IEnumerable<T> collection = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IEnumerable<T>>();
collection.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(enumerator);
```

However, I would *strongly* recommend against attempting to mock `IEnumerable`. Using a `List<>` with a single item in it is much easier to code initially and read later, and much less brittle:

```
List<T> listOfT = new List<T>
{
    MockRepository.GenerateStub<T>()
};
```

It's a really bad idea to stub/mock collection interface types - use the interface, by all means, but back it in your tests with an actual collection.

Comment: A neat answer. Ah, i knew we couldn't mock static functions. But this never struck me. Well, i really wish i could take your suggestion to not mock the IEnumerable interface. But, the way the code for which i am writing the unit test cases is written forces me to do so. Thanks a ton for the answer Chris.